# Substrings in the middle of a String in C

Tags: c, string, substring, extract, strncpy

I need to extract substrings that are between Strings I know.

I have something like `char string = "abcdefg";`
I know what I need is between `"c"` and `"f"`, then my return should be `"de"`.

I know the `strncpy()` function but do not know how to apply it in the middle of a string.

Thank you.

Comment: Show what you have tried so that we can correct your code

Comment: This definition is wrong `char string = "abcdefg"`.

Comment: We need to know *exactly* what you have, not something *like* you have.

Comment: Check the function:
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
 it's basically all you need. We'll be waiting for an updated version of your code :-)

Comment: Read up on `strchr`.  and/or `strpos`.

Comment: @dau_sama when did `strstr()` take a wildcard of unknown length?

Comment: @WeatherVane from cplusplus.com _Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1_ 
str2 will have to be null terminated to have it work, but that's not a big deal.

Comment: @dau_sama OP `strstr()` could only work as `strstr(string, "c*f")` where `*` is a wildcard for the unknown characters that OP is asking for. But it's a poorly worded question.

Comment: I didnt' want to to the homework for op :-)
you can combine two calls to strstr, first result is the beginning of your new string, second is the end.  You can then copy it in some other string and you'll be game.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a full, working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "abcdefg";

    char from[] = "c";
    char to[]   = "f";

    char *first = strstr(string, from);

    if (first == NULL) {
        first = &string[0];
    } else {
        first += strlen(from);
    }

    char *last = strstr(first, to);

    if (last == NULL) {
        last = &string[strlen(string)];
    }

    char *sub = calloc(strlen(string) + 1, sizeof(char));

    strncpy(sub, first, last - first);

    printf("%s\n", sub);

    free(sub);

    return 0;
}
```

You can check it at [this ideone](https://ideone.com/fpW2dO).

Now, the explanation:

**1.**

```
    char string[] = "abcdefg";

    char from[] = "c";
    char to[]   = "f";
```

Declarations of strings: main string to be checked, beginning delimiter, ending delimiter. Note these are arrays as well, so `from` and `to` could be, for example, `cd` and `fg`, respectively.

**2.**

```
    char *first = strstr(string, from);
```

Find occurence of the beginning delimiter in the main string. Note that it finds the *first* occurence - if you need to find the last one (for example, if you had the string `abcabc`, and you wanted a substring from the second `a`), it might need to be different.

**3.**

```
    if (first == NULL) {
        first = &string[0];
    } else {
        first += strlen(from);
    }
```

Handle situation, in which the first delimiter doesn't appear in the string. In such a case, we will make a substring from the beginning of the entire string. If it does appear, however, we move the pointer by length of `from` string, as we need to extract the substring beginning *after* the first delimiter (correction thanks to @dau_sama).
Depending on your specifications, this may or may not be needed, or another result might be expected.

**4.**

```
    char *last = strstr(first, to);
```

Find occurence of the ending delimiter in the main string. Note that it finds the *first* occurence.

As noted by @dau_sama, it's better to search for ending delimiter from the `first`, not from beginning of the entire string. This prevents situations, in which `to` would appear earlier than `from`.

**5.**

```
    if (last == NULL) {
        last = &string[strlen(string)];
    }
```

Handle situation, in which the second delimiter doesn't appear in the string. In such a case, we will make a substring until end of the string, so we get a pointer to the last character.
Again, depending on your specifications, this may or may not be needed, or another result might be expected.

**6.**

```
    char *sub = calloc(last - first + 1, sizeof(char));

    strncpy(sub, first, last - first);
```

Allocate sufficient memory and extract substring based on pointers found earlier. We copy `last - first` (length of the substring) characters beginning from `first` character.

**7.**

```
    printf("%s\n", sub);
```

Here's the result.

I hope it does present the problem with enough details. Depending on your exact specifications, you may need to alter this somehow. For example, if you needed to find *all* substrings, and not just the first one, you may want to make a loop for finding `first` and `last`.

Comment: if you check my stub answer, from where you got inspiration for yours, you'll find a problem with your approach. 
char *first = strstr(string, from);
char *last  = strstr(string, to);
last can be < first, depending on the pattern. I'll suggest you to call char *last  = strstr(first, to); instead

Comment: also you don't need to allocate a string so big:
char *sub = calloc(strlen(string) + 1, sizeof(char));
(last - first)+1 is enough

Comment: True. Included this in the answe as well.

Comment: also, your code won't work if the patterns are longer than one char, strstr returns you a pointer after the matched string! :-)

Answer (score 0):

TY guys, worked using the form below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *between_substring(char *str, char from, char to){
while(*str && *str != from)
    ++str;//skip
if(*str == '\0')
    return NULL;
else
    ++str;

char *ret = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
char *p = ret;
while(*str && *str != to){
    *p++ = *str++;//To the end if `to` do not exist
}
*p = 0;
return ret;
}

int main (void){
char source[] = "abcdefg";
char *target;
target = between(source, 'c', 'f');
printf("%s", source);
printf("%s", target);

return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since people seemed to not understand my approach in the comments, here's a quick  hacked together stub.

```
const char* string = "abcdefg";
const char* b = "c";
const char* e = "f";
//look for the first pattern
const char* begin = strstr(string, b);
if(!begin)
  return NULL;
//look for the end pattern
const char* end = strstr(begin, e);
if(!end)
  return NULL;
end -= strlen(e);

char result[MAXLENGTH];
strncpy(result, begin, end-begin);
```

Comment: Why `end -= strlen(e)`?

Comment: because the second pattern could be longer than 1 char, and strstr returns the pointer after the whole string has been matched.
if you had: const char* e = "fad" and in your string: "fadeee", it would return a pointer to the first "e", but if you want to cut out the whle string, you need to shift it left.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *between(const char *str, char from, char to){
    while(*str && *str != from)
        ++str;//skip
    if(*str == '\0')
        return NULL;
    else
        ++str;

    char *ret = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    char *p = ret;
    while(*str && *str != to){
        *p++ = *str++;//To the end if `to` do not exist
    }
    *p = 0;
    return ret;
}

int main(void){
    const char* string = "abcdefg";
    char *substr = between(string, 'c', 'f');

    if(substr!=NULL){
        puts(substr);
        free(substr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```